# add "x" icon that hides the current open accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

jQuery is still a learning process for me, but I have an accordion script here and I am looking to add a close icon to each toggle menu that will close the toggle once it has been opened, however I can't seem to get it to work. Thoughts?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82y7zb97/1/)

```
  $('#main').each(function () {
      var $accordian = $(this);
      $accordian.find('.view-m').on('click', function () {
          $accordian.find('.mobile-content-body').slideUp();
          $accordian.find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
          if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
              $(this).next().slideDown();
              $accordian.find('.close').slideToggle(500);
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82y7zb97/2/

Comment: This is great, but it toggles the other menus when the icon is clicked. I only want the icon to close the current open toggle menu. Any tips are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
$accordian.find('.close').slideToggle(500);
```

->

```
$accordian.find('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp(500);
});
```

Or

```
$accordian.find('.close').on('click',function() {
   $(this).parent().slideUp(500);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82y7zb97/4/)